# Jasmine test case error: spy error to have been called

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have the following code that needs to be tested in Jasmine

```
sampleMethod() {
  if (this.sampleObject) {
    // business logic
  } else {
    console.error('sampleObject not initialized');
  }
}
```

I had referred to [Spying on console.error() with Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519203/spying-on-console-error-with-jasmine) to add jasmine test to monitor console.error.

```
  it('should check for console.error', () => {
     spyOn(console, 'error');
     component.sampleMethod();
     expect(console.error).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Expected spy error to have been called.
```

SampleObject is undefined. I've also tried adding `spyOn` to `beforeEach`. Still, I'm getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this to ensure that `sampleObject` is undefined and try assigning the spy to a variable?

```
it('should check for console.error', () => {
     const errorSpy = spyOn(console, 'error');
     component.sampleObject = undefined;
     component.sampleMethod();
     expect(errorSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```